# Ускорение работы со строками

Tags: c, оптимизация, g++, c++

Имеется массив (1-10 элементов), состоящий из длинных (до 10000 символов) *неизменяемых* строк. Так же имеется одна (такая же длинная) строка, которая активно изменяется. Строки из массива очень активно сравниваются с изменяемой строкой.

К функциям добавил inline, к изменяемой строке добавил register, программа всё равно работает медленно. Массив строк реализован как string*, другая строка - просто string.

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно ускорить выполнение программы? Будет ли string.erase работать быстрее string.substr? Или в данном случае вообще лучше использовать классические char'овые строки вместо string'ов?

Заранее благодарен!

UPD: добавил немного кода

строка min-str не изменяется (просто хранит значение для sub-str) ( '_' не вставляется в сообщение)

```
sub_str = min_str.substr(j, i);
```

После того, как sub-str получает значение, проверяется выполнение функции

```
if (is_inside(sub_str, str, amount))
```

А это, собственно, сама функция, которая проверяет, входит ли подстрока во все строки заданного массива.

```
inline bool is_inside(string sub_str, string *str, int n)
{
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( str[i].find(sub_str) != -1 ) { m++ ;}
    }
    if (m == n) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

Только что понял, что программа должна работать быстрее, если я в функцию буду передавать значения по ссылке (или указателю). Есть ещё предложения?

Comment: если внутри inline функции есть цикл то она автоматически становится обычной

Comment: register для строки не поможет.
Показывайте код, как строкой манипулируете, может там в цикле складываете посимвольно, что очень медленно будет. Но можно заведомо сразу выделить немного места - быстрее будет.

Comment: Какие именно действия вы проводите с изменяемой строкой? Может быть, вам нужно [rope](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) или вообще связный список символов? Не пытайтесь мелкими подсказками компилятору выиграть в скорости, компиляторы сегодня не глупее нас с вами. Надо оптимизировать алгоритм и структуры данных.

Comment: @perfect: очччччень компиляторозависимо.

Comment: @Артём Девятов, а как именно сравниваются?

Comment: Если у вас паттерны постоянны, выполните над ними предобработку для более быстрого поиска. Например, попробуйте [вот этот алгоритм](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

Comment: @KoVadim, добавил код, некоторые пояснения и свои размышления

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Замечания по коду:
 1. Передаем строку по ссылке
 2. Прединкремент работает быстрее постинкремента
 3. Искать не все вхождения, а первое
 4. Правильно сравнивать с std::string::npos, а не с -1

Только эти микрооптимизации не сильно помогут, ибо оптимизируется наивный и неэффективный алгоритм со сложностью **O(k * N * N)** где к - количество элементов массива, N максимальная длина строки.
Замените std::string::find на быстрые [КМП](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0) или [Бойера-Мура](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) и получите **O(k * N)**
Ахо-Корасик не подойдет, т.к. решает обратную задачу.

PS. раз изменяется только искомая строка, можно подумать о специализированном алгоритме на основе префикс-функции.

Comment: @Dith: <зануда mode on>насчёт 2. я бы всё же заметил, что (1) для POD-типов преинкремент и постинкремент одинаковы, и (2) хороший оптимизатор (gcc, MSVC, Clang, Intel Compiler, Comeau) заметит, что результат не нужен, и произведёт одинаковый код.<зануда mode off>

Comment: @Dith: но +1 за микрооптимизации и анализ сложности алгоритма.

---
А разве КМП индексирует haystack?

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже показалось, что Ахо-Корасик решает немного другую задачу.
А насчёт 4 пункта - пришлось, скрипя зубами, написать -1, потому что npos в g++ не компилировался (в MSVS компилировался)

Comment: Угу, поэтому я его и убрал :-\

Comment: @VladD (1) оно таки да, только такой стиль можно считать преждевременной пессимизацией. КМП строит перфикс функцию обоих строк.  
@Артём Девятов это верно оочень старая версия g++

Comment: @Dith: по поводу постинкремента, я бы заметил, что он является устоявшейся идиомой для простых типов, и дополнительное время, потраченное на "ах да, преинкремент это же то же самое", не стоит того. (Я вообще сторонник [вот этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/467967/276994) мнения.)

Comment: @VladD Момент спорный, дабы не разводить холивары сошлюсь на наиболее авторитетный источник: Саттер/Александреску - Стандарты программирования C++, совет 9 и 28.

Comment: @Dith, не знаю, что имел в виду авторитет по поводу пре/пост инкрементов, но как и следовало ожидать, код функции автора что с i++, m++, что c ++i, ++m оттранслированный g++ -S одинаков.

Коды, полученные g++ -S -O3 естественно тоже совпадают.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, можно упростить код сравнения до вот такого:

```
bool is_inside(const string& sub_str, string str[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( str[i].find(sub_str) == -1 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Поскольку если вы уж нашли несовпадение, дальше можно не проверять.

Затем, вычислять подстроку -- излишнее копирование данных. Передавайте массив символов (по ссылке, конечно), и два индекса:

```
char* min_str_data = min_str.c_str(); // вычисляется один раз

if (is_inside(min_str_data, j, i, str, amount)) // ...

bool is_inside(
        const char* whole_str, int start_idx, int len,
        string str[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (str[i].find(whole_str, j, i) == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Так должно быть немного скорее.

Кроме того, уже давно не надо писать `inline`: смысл этого ключевого слова [не совсем такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971755/276994), как вы думаете.

Comment: Гениально! Метод от противного действительно будет работать намного быстрее
А что насчёт стрингов и чаров?

Comment: @Артём Девятов: добавил.

Comment: В if (str[i].find(whole_str, j, i) == -1) надо -1 заменить на string::npos.

Замена string на char[] скорее всего выигрыша не даст. Строго говоря, оно, конечно, зависит от реализации string, так что я бы тупо реализовал и замерил скорость.

Comment: @Пётр Таран: ТС писал, что у него проблемы с `npos`, a `-1` срабатывает. Моя замена не для ускорениям а для того, чтобы избежать ненужного копирования данных: `substr` создаёт копию данных, а нам она не нужна. А без `substr` не обойтись: `std::string::find` не имеет перегрузки с `std::string`, начальным индексом и длиной.

Answer (score 1):

Вычислять хэш для строк. Очевидно, что для статичных строк это надо сделать один раз. Рекомендую алгоритм FNV-1a, даже его 32-битный вариант очень хорош и крайне редко даёт коллизии. Для перестраховки можно взять 64-битный вариант, а вообще есть и 1024-битный.

```
unsigned long long fnv64_hash(const char* s)
{
    unsigned long long h = 14695981039346656037LL;
    while( *s ) {
        h ^= (unsigned long long)*s++;
        h *= 1099511628211LL;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: И как это приложить к вопросу автора?

Вычислить fnv для всех возможных подстрок в массиве неизменяемых строк?

--

Если уж всерьез заниматься ускорением поиска в описанной задачке, то наверное надо бы для каждой неизменной строки (в которой ищут подстроки) сделать индекс *пар символов* (в худшем случае 64K штук на строку), адресующий позиции таких пар в строке.

И вместо .find подстроки по всей строке смотреть strncmp искомой подстроки только в этих точках.

Если распределение символов в строках более-менее равномерное, то для строк по 10000 символов (IMHO) *все будет просто летать...*

Comment: Цитирую топикстартера: Имеется массив (1-10 элементов), состоящий из длинных (до 10000 символов) неизменяемых строк. Так же имеется одна (такая же длинная) строка, которая активно изменяется. Строки из массива очень активно сравниваются с изменяемой строкой.

Изменяем строку, вычисляем ее хэш. Если хэш совпал с одним из хэшей для неизменямой строки - значит, изменяемая строка совпала с ней (99.9999999%, но для полной уверенности можно strcmp сделать). Может, я чего-то недопонял? Может, я тут один такой дурак, который понимает буквально то, что видит, а другие додумывают, как бы играя в шарады

Comment: @VadimTukaev, отвечая на старые вопросы (от февраля 13-го года), желательно читать еще и уже сделанные ответы и комментарии.

Обычно открывается много информации, которую изначально автор не отобразил в первых строках своего вопроса. 

Например,

      inline bool is_inside(string sub_str, string *str, int n)
      {
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           if ( str[i].find(sub_str) != -1 ) { m++ ;}
       ....

и т.п., вокруг чего, собственно, и шла основная часть обсуждения здесь.

Comment: Это проблемы автора, не так ли? Я дал правильный ответ на тот вопрос, что он задал. Если у него другой вопрос - пусть задаёт другой вопрос.

http://hashcode.ru/questions/18428/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D1%81?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=314731#314731